# use ubuntu from a removable drive to work both on laptop and desktop computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, portable-harddrive

my laptop, which i run ubuntu on, is getting a bit old and i find it's getting slower and slower at running applications. My desktop computer is stronger, but I can't give up on the portability of my laptop.

I was thinking of installing a HD drawer for both my laptop and desktop. and when I come home just pull the HD from the laptop and plug it into the desktop.

I wanted to ask if anyone have tried it or have any inputs on the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works well. I have a pendrive that boots Ubuntu very fast even on my poor netbook.

And if you have enough space you don't need to re-install, you can copy the files from the root partition to the external medium, and after that you just need to setup the GRUB there.